# Check like operator pattern whether if its valid

Tags: vb.net

I have a TextBox where the user can write "Like pattern" to see if a string is matching. However if the user doesn't close the "[" the like operator will throw an error, that the argument is invalid for "pattern".

So I wrote something like this:

```
Private Function ValidateLikeString() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim valid As Boolean = DummyText Like TextBoxPrefix.Text
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The problem is the following: if DummyText is `123` and `TextBoxPrefix.Text` is `[1`, it will work just fine.

However if `TextBoxPrefix.Text` is `2[1`, it won't throw the exception because the first character won't match so the like operator will return false sooner than the exception is thrown. Of course if the DummyText will be 232 the exception will throw.

What I want to achieve is check `TextBoxPrefix.Text` against all cases if it's valid for pattern. I haven't found another case where the pattern is invalid only if the `[` isn't closed, but if there are other problematic strings I want a test on those too.